# Reactive Form to view / update not bound to FormBuilder

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

I'm going to apologize in advance as I think I'm missing something obvious here.

I'm new to coding and i'm trying to use the same form to view and edit data from a HTTP API. I can display the details of the record (code: code name and description) however the fields are not populated in my FormBuilder.

code-details.component.html

```
div *ngIf="code" class="card w-50 p-3">
    <h5 class="card-title">Code</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text"></p>
        <form [formGroup]="editCodeForm" novalidate>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text" name="id">{{code.id}}</span>
                    <input type="text" 
                        class="form-control" 
                        formControlName="codeName"
                        [value] ="code.codeName" 
                        placeholder="code name">

                    <input type="text" 
                        class="form-control" 
                        formControlName="description" 
                        [value] ="code.description" 
                        placeholder="description">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" 
                        [disabled]="editCodeForm.pristine" 
                        (click)="updateCode(this.editCodeForm.value)">Update
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"(click)="delete(this.editCodeForm.value)">Delete</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"routerLink="/add">New</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </form> 
    </div>
    <p>editCodeForm value: {{ editCodeForm.value | json}}</p>
</div>
```

code-details.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Code } from './code.component';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service'

import { 
  FormBuilder, 
  FormGroup, 
  FormControl,
  Validators 
} from '@angular/forms'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'code-details',
  templateUrl: './code-details.component.html'
})
export class CodeDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() code: Code[];
  editCodeForm

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,
    private api: ApiService,
    private fb : FormBuilder
  ) {

    this.editCodeForm = fb.group({
      id: [{value: null, disabled:true}],
      codeName: ['',Validators.required],
      description: [''],
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCode()
  }

  getCode(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    if (id) {
      this.api.getCode(id)
        .subscribe((code: Code[]) => this.code = code);
    }
  }
}
```

api.services.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Subject } from 'rxjs'
import { Code } from './codes/code.component'

@Injectable()

export class ApiService {

private selectedCode = new Subject<any>(); // holds reference to clicked item in list
codeSelected= this.selectedCode.asObservable(); // subscribe

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getCodes() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:58561/api/codes');
}
```

}

The form value's displayed at the bottom of the html page are empty when editing a form. I was trying to find a way for the data model to be presented in the form model so the user can update it and submit but it's currently not working.

Any pointers welcome :)

Cheers,
Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my application, I set up my form as follows:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productForm = this.fb.group({
        productName: ['', [Validators.required,
                           Validators.minLength(3),
                           Validators.maxLength(50)]],
        productCode: ['', Validators.required],
        starRating: ['', NumberValidators.range(1, 5)],
        description: ''
    });
}
```

Then when I get the data from the backend server, I do code like this to populate the form with data:

```
onProductRetrieved(product: IProduct): void {
    this.product = product;

    // Update the data on the form
    this.productForm.patchValue({
        productName: this.product.productName,
        productCode: this.product.productCode,
        starRating: this.product.starRating,
        description: this.product.description
    });
}
```

This is the method that gets the products and calls `onProductRetrieved:

```
getProduct(id: number): void {
    this.productService.getProduct(id)
        .subscribe(
            (product: IProduct) => this.onProductRetrieved(product),
            (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
}
```

And you may want to remove the `[value]` directive in your HTML so it is not competing with what the code above does.

You can find the complete set of code in my github here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms

In the folder `APM-Updated`

Comment: Thanks Deborah!

I tested your patchValue approach with text placeholder's and it indeed updated the form and the data model as hoped.

The challenge I'm having now is getting the data from the HTTP call into the patchValue code block.

I tried the following unsuccessfully:
  
getCode(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    if (id) {
      this.api.getCode(id)
        .subscribe((code: Code[]) => this.code = code);
      
      this.editCodeForm.patchValue({
        codeName: code.codeName,
        description: code.description
      })
    }

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to SO and it seems I can't format the code in the comment.

Comment: You can update the question with the new code or ask a new question. I updated my answer above.

Comment: That was great. Changing the subscribe line made it all click into place for me.

Really appreciate you sharing, thank you!!